# timestamp UTC+0 in java or kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, timestamp, datetime-format

Could someone know how to generate a timestamp format like this

```
“timestamp” : “2022-04-30T08:40:02.640+00:00”
```

I don’t recognize the format and don’t know how to generate it win kotlin, and it should be UTC+0.
There are so many way to generate time, datetime and timestamp…I’m confused.

Comment: *"I don’t recognize the format"* [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter` with `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` for this

In Java

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMillis).atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(hours, minutes));
String formatted = offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

In Kotlin

```
val offSetDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMillis).atOffset(oneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(hours, minutes))
val formatted = current.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
```

Output - `'2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'`

Comment: `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` prints varying numbers of decimals depending on the precision of the value of the formatted. Which is probably fine because the ISO 8601 standard allows such variation, so the receiver of the string should be able to handle it.